# AWS CLI query option when there is a period/dot in the attribute returned

Tags: aws-cli

Here is the command I am running

```
aws ssm describe-automation-executions \
    --filters "Key=ExecutionId,Values=b4a76700-50e0-4b3d-a790-d80a54ee91de" \
    --query "AutomationExecutionMetadataList[0].Outputs"
```

And the output is

```
{
    "createImage.ImageId": [
        "ami-0db79d4244a6501bc"
    ]
}
```

This is what I expect. However I want to further refine my query to select the `createImage.ImageId`, and because that attribute has a dot in it, the following query will not work

```
--query "AutomationExecutionMetadataList[0].Outputs.createImage.ImageId"
```

This returns `null` as the result output.

I have tried several other things but cant seem to select the `createImage.ImageId` attribute via the AWS CLI Query.
Is it possible to do this via the `--query` without using additional scripting tools (`jq` etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aws ssm describe-automation-executions \
        --filters "Key=ExecutionId,Values=b4a76700-50e0-4b3d-a790-d80a54ee91de" \
        --query 'AutomationExecutionMetadataList[0].Outputs."createImage.ImageId"'
```

After some experimentation, the above command ended up working.

On a side note, I noticed the AWS CLI query format is in this format documented here http://jmespath.org/

> The --query parameter accepts strings that are compliant with the JMESPath specification
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#cli-usage-output-filter